# Django Date Time Problems

Tags: django, date, time, types, field

This is really strange, I tried to add date time fields to my event model and I kept getting this error.

Events model looks like this ( at the momment)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_photoLink = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_fbLink = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Even though I take out the date time fields I had before, this error persists.
I can "makemigrations" but it fails to complete "migrate".

Oddly enough, the changes are reflected when I start the server :/

```
    Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying app.0015_event_date_published...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1322, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1274, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 60, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I tried flushing the database. I think the error is because I'm providing an incorrect type, but I'm not sure where ( this code worked fine before I had changed it to date/time)

On Django 1.8

Thanks

Comment: try removing migration from migration folder in your project

Comment: There is no migration inside my migration folder :/

Comment: are there any tables in your database?

Comment: Not currently, everything had been flushed

Comment: Yes there is, there is a migration 0015_event_date_published which is where the error is coming from.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: thanx for pointing it out

Comment: I deleted that, but it now just gives dependency errors

Comment: Ah yes, I solved it by replacing the date time fields with char fields until the dependenices went away on each error I kept getting. Thanks!